# How to undo things in Gnome desktop. CTRL+z not working in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: gnome, .desktop

I've installed Ubuntu 19.04 from scratch after an issue with my old Ubuntu installation.

I've found that now it uses Gnome instead of Unity. I like Gnome, but I have a couple of important usability issues that I assume are easily configurable, but I just don't know how to.

One of the main issues is that when doing anything in desktop before, like deleting a icon or moving it, I could easily press `CTRL + Z` and it would undo the action. **How may I do that now?**

I tried to search for these issues instead of asking, but I've not found anything that actually got them sorted.

Please note that I've installed [Gnome Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks).

Comment: See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1174965/248158) and the suggestions there.

Comment: I'll try to see if that extension helps me with this issue, looks promising. Thanks! @DKBose!

Comment: You can simply install the Unity desktop for 19.04 (updated version from 16.04) until the Gnome desktop bugs are worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found an answer to this! It'e extremely annoying and I don't understand why this question seems to be so uncommon (I didn't find anyone asking this, lt alone commenting on this!).

The problem is with the [Desktop Icons Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/). It does provide icons in the desktop, but in a weird way that its most annoying.

The solution? UNINSTALL IT FIRST and then install [Desktop Icons NG (DING) by rastersoft](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/).

[image]

That did solved my issue.