# Shortcut to access file properties (Alt+Enter) on desktop files works as just pressing the Enter key

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 19.10, shortcuts, file-properties

I'm looking for a shortcut to access the file properties for files on my desktop. The [official website](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-file-properties-basic.html.en) says that the shortcut is for this is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but it doesn't work because this key combination has the same effect as just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The shortcut works if the file/folder is inside a folder, but it doesn't work if the file/folder is on the desktop.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Defective keyboard? Try left-alt+enter, try right-alt+ enter, try a different keyboard

Comment: I tried, but nothing, it's very strange...if you tell me a keys' combination which includes alt, i'll try to use it to test the alt key; but i'm pretty sure that it works.

Comment: On my system, left-alt + enter opens file properties; right-alt + enter opens the file.

Comment: Hello @Jos i don't know what's the problem...i hope to solve it as soon as possible.

Comment: on mine it works with alt + central enter, not the small enter.

Comment: Hello @Jeison could you upload a video please?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the GNOME desktop environment, you should know that [GNOME removed desktop icons since version 3.28](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/01/gnome-desktop-icons-removed-3-28) and Ubuntu enables them using the [Desktop Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/) extension. This extension has very limited options though and hasn't seen much development.

The reason that you can't use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to display file properties from the desktop is simply because this option isn't implemented in the Desktop Icons extension.

The only alternatives to use this functionality for the moment is to access your desktop files from within Nautilus, or use another file manager (e.g. Nemo - see [How to set Nemo as the default file manager in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066752/how-to-set-nemo-as-the-default-file-manager-in-ubuntu)) to handle desktop icons, or use another desktop environment that offers this functionality.

Comment: Hello @BeastOfCaerbannong thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: You're welcome @GennaroArguzzi ! :)