# I can no longer drag and drop URL links from the Chrome browser to my `nemo` file manager

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, shortcuts, nemo, url

I [followed my instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066752/how-to-set-nemo-as-the-default-file-manager-in-ubuntu/1173861#1173861) years ago to make `nemo` my default file manager instead of `nautilus` (which is the default packaged with Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04, etc).

I used to be able to (for many years) hover my mouse over the little icon to the left of the URL in the address bar, and drag and drop shortcuts to URLs right into the nemo file manager. However, in the last 2 weeks to month or so (possibly as recently as the last 72 hrs, as I'm not actually sure when it quit working) I can no longer drag and drop links from the Chrome browser into my `nemo` file manager on Linux. **It still works fine from Firefox, but not Chrome.**

I tested it in **Chrome Version 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)** on both **Ubuntu 18.04 AND 20.04**--the result is the same--it's now broken. I submitted this information to Google (and so should you too please to get them to look at it!) via 3-dots in Chrome --> Help --> "Report an Issue...", but want to know if anyone else is experiencing this and if anyone else has found a work-around or fix to it for Ubuntu.

**Here is an animated .gif demonstrating this failed behavior** from Chrome. In the gif below, the **top-left window** is the `nano` text editor, zoomed way in. The **top-right window** is the `nemo` file manager. The **bottom-left** is the Firefox web browser on [this URL](https://itsfoss.com/convert-video-gif-linux/), and the **bottom-right** is the Chrome web browser (version specified above) on the same URL. I have the Chrome browser in the bottom-right in Incognito Mode (hence why it's dark) to prove it's not a plugin problem or something causing the failed behavior.

[image]

Comment: +1 googl chrome suddenly, will drag, but won't drop a location url onto the bookmarks bar