# Add a reload button in file manager (nautilus?)?

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, samba

The reload button long ago disappeared in Ubuntu's Files application (Nautilus?). It makes sense for new files to appear in a folder on a Samba server, for example, a downloaded file.

Now I have to leave the folder and open it again or I do a search for the file. Both options are extra meaningless work. Is it possible to adjust this behaviour with `dconf-editor` or something else, and if it is, how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to have the folder refreshed.

Alternatively, the button is already there, however not on the front. Click the down arrow (tooltip: View options), then "Reload".

Comment: <CTRL>R will also refresh.

Comment: Thanks! Plenty of choices, then. I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a file manager that hasn't been cut down to the bare minimum.

`nemo` still has the reload button.
(might need to be enabled in Preferences -> Toolbar)

```bsh
sudo apt install nemo
```

See here: [How to set Nemo as the default file manager in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066752/how-to-set-nemo-as-the-default-file-manager-in-ubuntu)