# How can I hide the home folder icon from Ubuntu 22.04 desktop

Tags: 22.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my computer. I want to remove the home folder icon from the desktop.

It used to be (20.04) that you could use this command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.desktop-icons show-home false`

You also used to be able to hide the home folder icon using Gnome Tweaks, but this option no longer exists.

Is there an equivalent that I can run in 22.04?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In "Settings", "Appearance", uncheck the option "Show Personal folder" in the section "Desktop Icons".

[image]

The setting `show-home` has moved to `org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding`, so the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-home false
```

will work in Ubuntu 22.04 and up.

Comment: +1 and a DING! for adding the ding. :D

Comment: seems need ubuntu >= 22

Comment: @yurenchen yes, old method is already in the question. User asks how it works in newer versions.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04.1, my "show personal folder" toggle switch in Settings is off, yet the home folder is still showing. I also tried "gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-home false", and restarting, to no effect. These did not show in Ubuntu 20. Something changed.

Comment: @vanadium On Ubuntu 22.04 I am getting `No such schema “org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding”`. Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 3):

Remove trash icon:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-trash false
```

Remove home icon:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-home false
```

To additionally hide the external drives:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-volumes false
```