# nemo error on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: nemo

A new Ubuntu user here, I want to replace nemo as my file manager, done everything else and it is working except this[image] error, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

when switching to nemo, did you remove the other file manager?

And then after removing the other filemanager/if not already removed, you can set up Nemo to handle the desktop completely with the following commands

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory
application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

then

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`

`gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true`

The first command disables the handling of desktop by Nautilus and the second one enables Nemo to take its place.

[source](https://itsfoss.com/install-nemo-file-manager-ubuntu/)

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @zx485 fixed, should look better now

Comment: @amar should look better now

Comment: Thanks I did what you suggested, running nemo interminal shows no errrs running sudo nemo however shows : WARNING **: 09:49:15.255: Current gtk theme is not known to have nemo support (Yaru-bark-dark) - checking...
ERROR SET META:15 Setting attribute metadata::nemo-list-view-sort-reversed not supported
and as soon as I change the view ERROR SET META:15 Setting attribute metadata::nemo-default-view not supported
ERROR SET META:15 Setting attribute metadata::nemo-icon-view-auto-layout not supported it seems whatever i do i get a warning, but I am more interested in solving the error issue.

Comment: I used this before I posted the question:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066752/how-to-set-nemo-as-the-default-file-manager-in-ubuntu/1446372#1446372. My nemo seems to be only in black and white, no colors in folders or anything,